# Inserir valores num array com dimensões definidas a partir de um loop

Tags: python, array, loop, numpy

Boa tarde, estou a tentar guardar valores na forma de um array a partir de diferentes ficheiros de texto, usando um loop. Necessito que os valores obtidos da primeira iteração sejam armazenados na primeira linha do array, os valores obtidos da segunda iteração no segundo array e assim sucessivamente... Tentei fazer isto criando inicialmente um array de zeros e depois substituindo os zeros pelos respetivos valores de cada iteração. No entanto finalizado o loop ficam apenas armazenados os valores da última iteração, ou seja, tenho um array de zeros menos na última linha. Algo estarei a cometer de errado mas não consegui ainda decifrar, alguém me consegue ajudar?
Deixo aqui um excerto do código.

```
nfile = 0
while nfile < 2:
    a = np.loadtxt('day_'+str(nfile)+'.txt', delimiter=",")
    amax = max(abs(a[:,0]))
    bmax = max(abs(a[:,1]))

    X = np.zeros((2, 2))
    X[nfile] = (amax, bmax)

    nfile = nfile + 1

print(X)
```

O output deveria ser:

```
array([[1.0404, 1.53  ],
       [1.4827, 0.73  ]])
```

Este é o output que obtive:

```
array([[0.    , 0.    ],
       [1.4827, 0.73  ]])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que você está recriando o array a cada iteração dentro do loop:

X = np.zeros((2, 2))

Esse trecho precisa estar antes do while.

Answer (score 0):

Muitos dos problemas apresentados aqui no site envolvendo numpy e pandas podem ser resolvidos na leitura do dados, assim evitando processamento desnecessários. Por isso por vezes aos APs são pedidos código e amostras de dados pois um detalhe faz a diferença.

```
import numpy as np
#Simula um conjunto de arquivos para teste...
from io import StringIO 

d = {
    "day_0.txt": StringIO("1,0\n1.0404,-1\n0,1.53"),
    "day_1.txt": StringIO("1,0.73\n1.4827,0\n1,0")
}
#...fim da simulação.


X = np.zeros((2, 2))
for n in range(0,2):
    X[n] = tuple(map(max, abs(np.loadtxt(d['day_'+str(n)+'.txt'], delimiter=",", unpack=True))))

print(X)
```

<sup>Teste no [ideone.com](https://ideone.com/FVDkcK)</sup>

Para chegar a esse código primeiro temos que consertar o exemplo:

```
nfile = 0
X = np.zeros((2, 2))      # Muda o posicionamento da inicialização do array que conterá os resultados.
while nfile < 2:
    a = np.loadtxt('day_'+str(nfile)+'.txt', delimiter=",")
    amax = max(abs(a[:,0]))
    bmax = max(abs(a[:,1]))

    #X = np.zeros((2, 2))  
    X[nfile] = (amax, bmax)

    nfile = nfile + 1

print(X)
```

Repare que faz duas chamadas de abs() para obter os valores absolutos de todos os elementos do arquivo o que pode ser simplificado para uma única chamada.

```
nfile = 0
X = np.zeros((2, 2))      
while nfile < 2:
    #Faz uma única chamada de abs
    a = abs(np.loadtxt('day_'+str(nfile)+'.txt', delimiter=","))
    amax = max(a[:,0]))       #Removida a chamada local de abs()
    bmax = max(a[:,1]))       #Removida a chamada local de abs()

    X[nfile] = (amax, bmax)

    nfile = nfile + 1

print(X)
```

Depois use o parâmetro `unpack=True` em ['np.loadtxt()'](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) para desempacotar as colunas em duas variáveis assim os fatiamentos `amax = max(a[:,0]))` e `bmax = max(a[:,1]))`.

```
nfile = 0
X = np.zeros((2, 2))      
while nfile < 2:
    #Desenpacota as colunas em a e b.
    a, b = abs(np.loadtxt('day_'+str(nfile)+'.txt', delimiter=",", unpack=True))
    #amax = max(a)       #Remove código redundante.
    #bmax = max(b)       #Remove código redundante.

    X[nfile] = (max(a), max(b))

    nfile = nfile + 1

print(X)
```

Ao invés de fazer duas chamada de `max()` aplique faça um `map()` e gere uma [`tupla`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple) com os resultados.

```
nfile = 0
X = np.zeros((2, 2))      
while nfile < 2:
    #Aplica max a colunas desempacotas gerando uma tupla e salvando X.
    X[nfile] = tuple(map(max, abs(np.loadtxt('day_'+str(nfile)+'.txt', delimiter=",", unpack=True))))      

    #X[nfile] = (max(a), max(a))     #Removido código desnescessário.

    nfile = nfile + 1

print(X)
```

E finalmente simplifique o método de leitura dos arquivos.

```
import numpy as np

X = np.zeros((2, 2))      
for nfile in range(0,2):
    X[nfile] = tuple(map(max, abs(np.loadtxt('day_'+str(nfile)+'.txt', delimiter=",", unpack=True))))          

print(X)
```